# PL/SQL ORACLE FUNCTION

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to make function to count my all ID.
But my function does not work. Do not know why ?
I am using Oracle SQL Developer.

```
CREATE FUNCTION policz(wartosc as NUMBER) 
RETURN INT
IS
ile INT
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(Id) INTO ile FROM t_dane
RETURN ILE;
end;
```

Comment: What do you mean with "does not work"? Are you having an error, an unexpected result, ... ?

Comment: ORA-06575: Package or function POLICZ is in an invalid state
06575. 00000 -  "Package or function %s is in an invalid state"
*Cause:    A SQL statement references a PL/SQL function that is in an
           invalid state. Oracle attempted to compile the function, but
           detected errors.
*Action:   Check the SQL statement and the PL/SQL function for syntax
           errors or incorrectly assigned, or missing, privileges for a
           referenced object.
Error at Line: 1 Column: 8

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon at the end of `ile  INT` and another at the end of `SELECT COUNT(Id) INTO ile FROM t_dane`. Add those two characters and you should be good. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

You say you're USING Oracle SQL Developer.

But are you REALLY?

[image]

The plsql editor shows you quote clearly where your issues are and how to fix them.

Your original code has problems on the first line. You'll notice squiggles on the NUMBER in your parameter declaration - that's because we don't recognize the 'AS' as a valid keyword in your plsql block.

Remove the AS.

Compile.

See errors.

Fix errors.

Compile.

Repeat.

Assuming you have a table named T_DANE with a column named ID, you should be good to go.

```
create or replace FUNCTION policz(wartosc   NUMBER) 
RETURN INT
IS
ile INT;
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(Id) INTO ile FROM t_dane;
RETURN ILE;
end;
```

Once it compiles without errors, hit the 'green play button' to generate the script to execute your stored proc. Put in the value for 'wartosc' and hit 'OK.'

At the bottom of the screen you'll see an 'output variables' panel. Click on it. You'll see the value returned for ile.

Then, you'll truly be using Oracle SQL Developer.

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues in your code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION policz(wartosc NUMBER)
    RETURN INT IS
    ile                                     INT;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(Id) INTO ile FROM t_dane;

    RETURN ILE;
END;
```

Also, the `wartosc` parameter is unuseful: you never use it.

Comment: CREATE or replace FUNCTION policz 
RETURN NUMBER 
IS
ile NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO ile FROM PACJENT;
RETURN ILE;
end;

It works.